# web api is receiving nulll values from angularjs post request

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am sending a CORS request from my angular js application using $http service to asp.net web api.(web api 2.0).

My post request to web api.

js and chrome data:
[image]

When the request reaches to web api, the data becomes null.

data in visual studio:
[image]

my web api configuration.

[image]

Angularjs and web api applications are running in localhost with different ports.

Can any one suggest me, How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code here so we can better assist you :)

Comment: Please check the images.

Comment: Try `data: newBookmark` instead of `data: {'bookmark':newBookmark}`.

Comment: I tried the same, but no luck..

Comment: The data you are posting is not serialized correctly to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Try using the `$httpParamSerializer` (v1.4.0).

Comment: I tried your approach, but no luck. my $http config is like below. `**app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);**` ,

Comment: Is there any need for the content-type to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? If not, try changing it to `application/json` and do not use the `$httpParamSerializer`.

Comment: When I change the `Content-Type` to `application/json`, request is not reached to web api. because of that i am using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: When i change the content type to **application/json**, i am getting the following error. `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:49877/api/bookmarks. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405`.  @peco